# Why is my RAM (16G) being completely used up?

Tags: linux, mysql, unix, memory

When I do "top", I only see that mysqld is using 70% of Memory.
Nothing else.

Why is it being used up?

Comment: need more info here chief, maybe some details on whats running or mysql config?

Answer (score 7):

Linux takes advantage of all the memory available to it.

If there is memory that is not being specifically used by applications, the OS will use it for cacheing to speed up other processes.

No use letting useful resources sit there unused :)

Comment: +1 - RAM that is un-utilised (esp. in a server) is going to waste

Comment: Funny how everybody is complaining about Windows doing the same.

Answer (score 5):

Mysql (and any other SGBD) are trying to load the most data possible in memory because it is some much quicker to get data from RAM than an hard drive.

This is a *normal* behavior on Linux (probably most unix, and maybe windows ?) systems behave like this. The more you have in memory, quicker the *software* runs.

Comment: SGBD == DBMS, just in case anyone (like me) was wondering - save you googling it :)

Comment: Yes, sorry.. SGBD is, at least, the french one.. My bad..

Answer (score 0):

Use "free -m" to get a clearer picture of what your memory is being used for.